# CSS breaking on Deployment via "react-scripts build" command

Tags: css, reactjs, pagination, react-redux

I am working on an application where during development the CSS of react-paginate shows up just fine, but when i deploy the app on a server(for prod) the CSS generated for "Pagination" class is missing which results in broken CSS for the directive.
Attached image[image] here.

How to fix this?

So this is the way, i imported

```
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate'; 
Version -> "react-paginate": "^5.2.3",

<ReactPaginate
                  previousLabel={'previous'}
                  nextLabel={'next'}
                  breakLabel={<a href="">...</a>}
                  breakClassName={'break-me'}
                  pageCount={this.props.visitorTotalcount / this.props.limit}
                  onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}
                  marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                  pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                  subContainerClassName={'pages pagination'}
                  containerClassName = {'pagination'}
                  activeClassName={'active'}
                  disableInitialCallback={false}
                  />
```

Comment: Just that section breaks? We'd need to see the css rules as well as the dom structure

Comment: Did you check the path for this CSS file, i think it is not working because the path can't be seen

Comment: @SergChernata Updated the query, pls have a look.